# QR code in Cordova without using plugins

Tags: angularjs, cordova, qr-code

I'm trying to use QRCode Read/scan in a Cordova application.
But I'd like to do it without using the camera plugin.

For this, I found the great jsqrcode library: https://github.com/LazarSoft/jsqrcode

As I'm using Angular as a framework, there is a wrapper of the jsqrcode library: https://github.com/sembrestels/angular-qr-scanner

When I launch the app in a web browser (chrome/OSX) using `cordova serve android`, this perfectly works (ie. I can see the camera display).

But when I run the app in the device (android nexus 7) using `cordova run --device`, instead of seeing the camera of my nexus 7, I see a grey square with a multimedia icon inside.

Is there something special to do? The camera permissions are already granted in manifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

I read that the browser need to have the getUserMedia capability. Maybe Cordova is not capable?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: It's probably because in-line webcam isn't supported. Most mobile OS will call the native camera software to take the picture for you and you can get it as a jpg or as an HTML blob.

Comment: So you think I have to forget this idea? It's really impossible to use HTML5 camera capabilities in Phonegap Cordova?

Comment: According to the documentations of jsqrcode, it can load a JPG into the canvas and decode the QR from there. Why don't you try to use Cordova's Media plugin to capture an image, then use File plugin to load the image into your HTML canvas.